# Executing all text files in one folder by a batch script

Tags: batch-file

How do I use all the .txt files in a particular folder as input into my batchscript, without having to hardcode their names individually?

In short: I want the batch script to process all the .txt files in the directory it resides in.

Current code:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in (filename1.txt) do (...)
```

...which reads only one.

I've tried the following methods that do not work:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in ('dir /b C:\BatchScripting') do (..)
```

And:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in (*.txt) do (...)
```

And this too:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in (%%~dpnx) do (...)
```

But to no avail. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after this

```
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in (%%x) do (...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be a lot easier to answer if you were a little more specific about what you wanted to achieve.  Here's a possible solution based on my interpretation of your question; use a FOR loop on the command line as shown below

```
FOR %A IN *.txt DO CALL <batch_script> [parameters]
```

The general form of the statement above is

```
FOR %A IN (list) DO command [ parameters ]
```

where (list) is the set of items on which you want to perform and operation
command is any internal/external command or a batch script as shown.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. Basically, my issue is, currently the input code is at:

`FOR %A IN *.txt DO CALL <batch_script> [parameters]`

Which calls only one file. I need it to call _all_ the .txt files from the folder where the batch script is placed.

And substituting the filename with * didn't work.

Comment: @Shalapolia: Your question sounds very general, and this answer, in my view, is perfectly valid. I do realise, however, that it may not apply in your situation. Therefore, please edit your question to give more details about what your batch script is doing and what you mean by calling *all* the .txt files.

Comment: My apologies! Very new to batch scripting. I've edited the question. Hopefully more detailed.